# Hive case-insensitive alphabetical sorting

Tags: sorting, hadoop, hive, hql, lts

When I have an "order by" clause inside of a hive query, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY category_name
```

The results will be sorted as all the capital letters first and then all the lower letters. I need some table constraint or configuration to enforce the below behavior. A session sorting with UPPER/LOWER won't help.

**Current results:**

```
AAA
KKK
ZZZ
aaa
bbb
yyy
```

**Expected results:**

```
aaa
AAA
bbb
KKK
yyy
ZZZ
```

Is there any configuration which enforces hive to sort the data Alphabetical sorting first?

Within sql it's a collation. Within oracle it's LTS.

What is the right configuration for this kind of expected sorting results, and where to set it?

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `lower()`?

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY LOWER(category_name);
```

Note:  this will be arbitrary about the case of the result.  Because lower-case letters come after upper case in all modern collations, you could do:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM categories c
ORDER BY LOWER(c.category_name), c.category_name DESC;
```

Comment: I have other tool that query the tables. So i want some table constraint/ configuration to enforce it to behave like i mention.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement the alphabetical sorting or any kind of sorting you can use cluster by in your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
cluster BY LOWER(category_name);
```

You can alternatively use the distribute by with sort by option for more customized solution. 
SELECT * 
FROM categories 
DISTRIBUTE BY LOWER(category_name) 
SORT BY LOWER(category_name) DESC